# Is JDK 11 supported in Cassandra 3.0.x?

Tags: java, cassandra, java-11, cassandra-3.0

I want to upgrade jdk for my webapp. But cassandra versions are of 3.0.15. Is there a way to make cassandra 3.0.15 work with JDK 11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 11 is only supported in Apache Cassandra 4.0 (see [NEWS.txt](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0.2/NEWS.txt#L42)).

Only Java 8 is supported for earlier versions of Cassandra. You will not be able to start Cassandra otherwise. Cheers!

Comment: is there a way around this so that I can run Cassandra 3.0.15 with JDK 11?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It isn't supported. Cheers!